# Regular expression to strip everything between anchor tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to strip out all the links and text between anchors tags from a html string as below:

```
 string LINK_TAG_PATTERN = "/<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/a>";

 htmltext = Regex.Replace(htmltext, LINK_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
```

This is not working anyone have ideas why?

Thanks a lot,

Edit: the regex was from this link [Extract text and links from HTML using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991337/extract-text-and-links-from-html-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: If you're trying to process HTML/XML with RegEx, take note that it won't work, as I do believe that HTML/XML is a context free language, but not a Regular Language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems in your string: Unnecessary slash at the beginning (that's Perl syntax), unescaped backslash (`\b`), unnecessary escaped backslash (`\\`).

So, if it **has** to be a Regex, taking all warnings into account that enough other people have linked to, try

```
string LINK_TAG_PATTERN = @"<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>";
htmltext = Regex.Replace(htmltext, LINK_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The `\b` is necessary to prevent other tags that start with `a` from matching.

Answer (score 4):

Use an HTML Parser and not Regular Expressions to parse HTML.

[HTML Agiliity Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to troubleshoot regular expressions.  You can find a library of regular expressions [here](http://regexlib.com/).

You might consider using javascript to walk the DOM tree for your replacements instead of regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
string LINK_TAG_PATTERN = @"(<a\s+[^>]*>)(.*?)(</a>)";

htmltext = Regex.Replace(htmltext, LINK_TAG_PATTERN, "$1$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, this only strips links of a very special kind (e.g. your regex does not match upper-case A which is perfectly valid in HTML: `<A ...>bla</A>`. The replacement wouldn't work for javascript links either. Is your code relevant to user security?