# Regex to extracting links from HTML

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extract text and links from HTML using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991337/extract-text-and-links-from-html-using-regular-expressions)

Given an string containing HTML such as:

> ```
>        <td scope="row">1</td> 
>         <td scope="row"></td> 
>         <td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/directory.htm">directoryfile.htm</a></td> 
>         <td scope="row">directoryfile</td> 
>         <td scope="row">104569</td> 
>      </tr> 
>      <tr class="blueRow"> 
>         <td scope="row">2</td> 
>         <td scope="row"></td> 
>         <td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/historicaldata.htm</a></td> 
>         <td scope="row">historicaldata</td> 
>         <td scope="row">40361</td> 
>      </tr> 
>      <tr> 
>         <td scope="row">&nbsp;</td> 
>         <td scope="row"><span class="blue">Complete submission text file</span></td> 
>         <td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/businessagenda.txt</a></td> 
>         <td scope="row">businessagenda;</td> 
>         <td scope="row">146701</td>
> ```

I want to just grab the link for historicaldata using regex. However, it seems that my program is not finding the link and I do not see the problem as the regex works on the tester. Can you guys see what's the problem?

I understand that regex is not the best thing to use with HTML but I just want to try it. Thanks everyone!

> Pattern data = Pattern.compile("Archives.*\s.*historicaldata");
>   Matcher test1= data.matcher(inputHTML);
>   while (test1.find()) {
>   System.out.println("Test: Now matching"); // Doesn't print
>   }

Comment: Duck, before the "ARRGGH! Parsing Html with Regex!" crowd throws a shoe at you.

Comment: Too late, [shoe's already been thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I'll see your "parsing html with regex" and raise you "tables for layout", "css class named for color", and ".htm instead of .html in filename"

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to match 'Archives\historicaldata' then your regex string should be
`"Archives\/historicaldata"` in fact you may be able to use `"Archives/historicaldata"`

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `"Archives.*\s.*historicaldata"`

```
Pattern data = Pattern.compile("Archives.*\s.*historicaldata");
```

the `\s` means whitespace[1], and since there is no whitespace in `"/Archives/directory.htm"` it doesn't match. Try just

```
Pattern data = Pattern.compile("Archives.*historicaldata");
```

[1] The "\s" is incorrect also - to get that in the pattern you have to escape the backslash so it becomes "Archives.*\s.*historicaldata"